# I'm struggling with a reverse ssh tunnel setup. command looks correct, but no traffic flows

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

In my house I have a NAT firewall which has exposed port 7022 externally, mapped internally to port 22 of one of my machines, lets call it alpha.  This machine has a user account "external" with public keys of all the players in this scenario in its `authorized_keys` file

At another site which I can only get to at the moment via a windows virtual machine which has a vpn setup to access the remote location.  In order to access a remote rapsberry pi there (beta) the command used for that is `ssh -nNT -R 9000:beta:22 me@charlie` which I issue using `git bash` on my windows virtual machine and where charlie is my desktop machine (debian linux) and the remote raspberry pi is called beta Once my windows machine has set up this tunnel I can ssh into the beta to do stuff.

Its a bit of a bind to have this windows vm machine in the middle as I have to run it up and establish all the connections every time I want to do something.  I also have to do https requests from that to view whats going on and at the moment I can only do that from the virtual machine.

So I'm trying to find a way for the remote pi (beta) to automatically create a ssh tunnel so as to avoid the windows machine in the middle. If I can get it to work I'm thinking a systemd service run at boot time (infrequently - once every year or so) to create the tunnel will be much more convenient.

So far I have taken the following steps.

On the beta I have issued this command `ssh -p 7022 -nNT -R alpha:40022:localhost:22  external@example.com -v`. The -v shows success (apparently) in creating this tunnel

On alpha I have issued this command `sudo lsof -i TCP:40022` and what I see is that before I issued the above ssh command there was nothing, but afterwards there is something there.  I think this proves that the ssh tunnel is being setup through my firewall correctly.

However when from my desktop I issue `ssh -p 40022 external@alpha -v` the debug shows connecting to alpha on port 40022 but then nothing more.

I am a total loss as to how to go further.  Another question I made recently is asking about using my routers l2tp vpn capability to try a similar thing, but nothing there either.  This ought to be easier, but I am not finding it so.

How to I debug this?  Is there anything wrong with my commands that I am not noticing?

Edit
As requested here is the output of `sudo lsof -i TCP:40022` once I've tried to connect from beta.

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    4127 external   10u  IPv4 50793481      0t0  TCP *:40022 (LISTEN) 
sshd    4127 external   11u  IPv6 50793482      0t0  TCP *:40022 (LISTEN)
```

Note since doing this I've also edited alpha's `sshd_config` file to have `GatewayPorts yes` set (and restarted service).  It doesn't appear to make a difference

Comment: What "something" exactly does `lsof` show? Specifically, what address:port (not just port) is it listening on?

Comment: @u1686_grawity ```COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    4127 external   10u  IPv4 50793481      0t0  TCP *:40022 (LISTEN)
sshd    4127 external   11u  IPv6 50793482      0t0  TCP *:40022 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

Before I had the new router in place alpha had been in my DMZ of the old router (it could not forward port 25 so that was the only choice).  As a result it had a firewall in place of its own.

Remove its firewall and bingo everything started working

Sorry for the noise